# Even doInBackground of AsyncTask runs in background, then what is the advantage of AsyncTask loader's loadInBackground() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loader

Similar to doInBackground() of AsyncTask, asynctask loader's callback method onLoadFinished() will run in background and gets the response from the URL and then the response is sent to onLoadFinished() of LoaderManager to append the response to views, which may or maynot run on main UI thread. similar to onPostExecute(). I wanted to know what is the real advantage here if I use AsynctaskLoader or LoaderManager

Comment: `AsyncTask` does not bode well with Activity Life Cycle. For instance if the `AsyncTask` is running and the user rotates the device and activity is restarted the you'll see some strange behavior. The reason is `AsyncTask` still hangs on to the previous instance of the Activity which was destroyed during on onRotate. `AsyncTaskLoader` was designed to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is different purpose to them. LoaderManager userd to load data from some source. And AsyncTask just used to do something in background.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) is some explanation  to this. As you can see

- If you fetch the data directly in the activity or fragment, your
  users will suffer from lack of responsiveness due to performing
  potentially slow queries from the UI thread.
- If you fetch the data from another thread, perhaps with AsyncTask,
  then you're responsible for managing both the thread and the UI
  thread through various activity or fragment lifecycle events, such as
  onDestroy() and configurations changes.

And also

> Loaders solve these problems and includes other benefits. For example:
>
> - Loaders run on separate threads to prevent janky or unresponsive UI.
> - Loaders simplify thread management by providing callback methods when
>   events occur.
> - Loaders persist and cache results across configuration changes to prevent duplicate queries.
> - Loaders can implement an
>   observer to monitor for changes in the underlying data source. For
>   example, CursorLoader automatically registers a ContentObserver to
>   trigger a reload when data changes.